# How to simplify this radical?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I go about simplifying such a problem? $\sqrt{3}(4-2\sqrt{6})$

I'm not really used to doing this type of problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "solving" this problem? Do you mean how to simplify the expression?

Comment: "Simplify", yes.

Comment: Is the $4-\sqrt 6$ under the radical sign?  If so, it is negative and there is no square root.  Just report that fact.  If not, distribute the $\sqrt 3$ into the parentheses.  What is $\sqrt 3 \cdot \sqrt 6?$

Comment: No, it's exactly as written -- on one line, mate. Thanks for both tips!

Comment: Would that be √18?

Answer (score 1):

You can do $$\sqrt 3(4-2\sqrt 6)=4\sqrt 3-2\sqrt{3 \cdot 6}=4\sqrt 3-6\sqrt 2$$